# How can I convert a std::vector<unsigned short> to std::vector<int>?

Tags: c++, vector

I have found this question a few times, but none of them seem to offer a good answer (please mark as duplicate if I missed it).

I have a method that returns a `std::vector<unsigned short>`, but I want to allow for more numbers than an unsigned short can hold, so I would like to convert it to a `std::vector<int>` before I add my bigger numbers to it.

So I want to convert it while keeping the data & order intact. A `std::vector<unsigned short>` that contains `[1, 2, 3]` should contain `[1, 2, 3]` after it has been converted to `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Why not using range constructor?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan yes this is what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Just construct the `std::vector<int>` from the `std::vector<unsigned short>`:

```
std::vector<unsigned short> org_vec;

// ...

std::vector<int> int_vec(std::begin(org_vec), std::end(org_vec));
```